# ObjectiveC: something between return value and method name

Tags: objective-c, syntax, methods

I am trying to understand the meaning of that "something" before the method name in objC. Here an example:

```
- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker 
      shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person 
                                property:(ABPropertyID)property 
                              identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier
```

The method name is `shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson`, the method has three parameter and has a return value `(BOOL)` but what is the role of `peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)`?

It isn't the return value, it isn't the method parameter (because cames before the method name), and so what is it?

Comment: See this - [The Objective-C Programming Language - Message Syntax](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocObjectsClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH11-SW6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In objective c the method is split up into 4 components (or so I would guess as this is how I see it)

I'll break up this method:

```
- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker 
      shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person 
                                property:(ABPropertyID)property 
                              identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier
```

the `-` signifies that it's an instance method, you need to allocate an instance of this class to use it.

the `(BOOL)` signifies that it should return a `BOOL`, `YES` or `NO`.

the method is defined by a selector uid, `peoplePickerNavigationController:shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:property:identifier:`

That is the full method name unlike what you have said.

the last part are the parameters. Those are pretty self explanatory.

Comment: Ok, talking more Java like this method has 4 parameters: peoplePicker,person,property and identifier. Is it correct? thanks!

Comment: yes, note that the class of these parameters is denoted by the (Class) beforehand after the :

Answer (score 1):

Actually, in this case the method name is

```
peoplePickerNavigationController:shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:property:identifier:
```

And it has 4 arguments.

This is kind of a special case since this is a method of a protocol.
In general you don't call/send methods of protocols, they are called and you are supposed to implement them to react appropriately to a certain situation.

As said in other answers too, you are given the `peoplePickerNavigationController` because it could be the case you have various controllers and you don't want to do the same thing for all of them. :) You use it to differentiate between them.

If you were to call this method by your own then having the first argument would be some how redundant (Since in most cases you will already know that information)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The role of the `peoplePickerNavigationController:` parameter is to allow multiple ABPeoplePickerNavigationController objects to use a single instance of your object as a delegate.

And this way, if there are multiple ABPeoplePickerNavigationController objects, you'll know  which picker did the picking (and called into your delegate method).

Hope this helps clear up your confusion!

Answer (score 0):

Method name is not `shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson` but `peoplePickerNavigationController:shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:property:identifier:`, and it takes 4 arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Presuming you are talking 'in general' and not specifically about this method.

Well it is all part of the signature of the method.  Each part with a colon (:) before it is a string which is all part of the method name in effect.

Answer (score 0):

No, the method name (or strictly speaking, the selector) is

```
peoplePickerNavigationController:shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:property:identifier:
```

It is just that its first parameter is the navigation controller sending the message.  This is so that the receiver knows which object sent the message.  It's a standard paradigm for delegate methods, so one object can be delegate for more than one other object.

Answer (score -1):

The method name is `peoplePickerNavigationController`, not "shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson". In fact, the method's signature is `peoplePickerNavigationController:shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:property:identifier:`, because in Objective-C method names / signatures are composed of all arguments.

Comment: Ok, Maybe now I've understood. method name is peoplePickerNavigationController and shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson is one of four parameters. is it correct? thanks!

Comment: The method _name_ is `peoplePickerNavigationController:shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:property:identifier:`. The _signature_ is something completely different; in Obj-C, it describes the types of the return value and the parameters. @user